# Multiple interface implementations Android

Tags: java, android, interface, callback, this

I have an Activity which implements two interfaces for call backs on certain actions. I want to send a context of my Activity to another Class which will access the object of the specified callback.

Here is my code :-

```
     public class OpenSchoolFragment extends Fragment implements IOpenSchoolCallBack, INetworkCallback
    {
// 1st case
       expandableListAdapter = new AdapterOpenSchool(getActivity(), this); // IOpenSchoolCallBack should provided

//2nd case
call.enqueue(new Callback<OpenSchool>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OpenSchool> call, Response<OpenSchool> response)
            {

                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    OpenSchool userBatch = response.body();
                    if (userBatch != null)
                    {
                        RLProgressRoot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    RLProgressRoot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (response.code() == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.integer_404))
                    {
                        DialogHelperUtil.showRetrySnackbar(RLContainer, getString(R.string.str_error_unauthorised),this); //INetworkCallBack should be provided

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DialogHelperUtil.showMessageSnackbar(RLContainer, response.raw().message());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

So when I try to pass "this" in the second case, I get an error saying :-

```
Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'Callback<OpenSchool>', required: 'INetworkCallback'
```

How can I make sure the right callback is passed in "this" for the second case ie. `INetworkCallback`?

Comment: The error looks wrong. I feel there's something you're not showing us, like the second statement is called from an inner class or something.

Comment: not sure, but try cast this to INetworkCallback, like `(INetworkCallback) this`

Comment: @Michael Yes the second case is in an inner class. Updating my question

Comment: @user3034944 Then use `OpenSchoolFragment.this` instead of `this`

Comment: @Michael thanks, this was the issue

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "this" refers to the current object in which you are in that precise point.

If your `DialogHelperUtil.showRetrySnackbar()` is called from `Callback` class, then `this` refers to `Callback`.

You can "exit" current inner-Class (`Callback`) and reach its outer-class by using `OuterClass.this`